# Resetting MediaPlayer onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, progressdialog, back

I want to have the possibility of cancel the load of current Android MediaPlayer URL when pressing back button (onBackPressed) and quit to the previous activity as if there was nothing.
This all happens while Activity loads.
onCreate has a ProgressDialog call. I want to cancel this dialog, cancel the creating/starting MediaPlayer and go back.

How to make it correctly?

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 if (pd!=null) {if (mp3Service!=null) mp3Service.reset(getApplicationContext()); pd.onBackPressed();};
 super.onBackPressed();

 }
```

This doesn't work, moreover, in some time the screen begins to darken and hang the APP.

What's wrong, maybe I must call another thread? (playSong launches in separate thread).

Answer (score 1):

If your progress dialog is visible then you need to override its onBackPressed method to handle the event:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(this) {
  public void onBackPressed() {
    dismiss();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
  }
};
pd.setTitle("Loading");
pd.setMessage("Please Wait..");
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.show();
```

Comment: Thanks. It does almost what is needed besides that after going to previous screen the music starts playing... .stop() crashes (NullPointerException), .reset() with .release() also don't cancel the music to load.

Comment: So you hit back, cancel the dialog, stop the media-player and go to the previous activity .. but you get a NullPointer ? .. what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: I'll put it later. Maybe stop() must be changed to reset()? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29 - if player is initializing, this can cause error.

Comment: The state diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html is quite useful. Make sure you are using prepareAsync if its getting called on the ui thread.

Comment: I've added if (mplayer!=null) in Service's onDestroy, and NullPointer disappeared. But the music won't stop.

Comment: The play is in another thread, but for some reason it won't stop

Comment: So your player is running inside a service and while the player is loading you display a progress dialog, and when you hit back you are dismissing the dialog and destroying the service, which stops the player, but the player keeps playing ?

Comment: Not sure why was called OnDestroy, but when hitting back normally it must stay at the background playing. Only in this case I want to stop it - if the user hits back while loading. The problem is I can't stop the player to run. Calling only stop() doesn't stop player to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could either try to check for `OnCancelListener`in your dialog to the detect if your dialog has been canceled. Or you can try something like this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        //Do your code here for canceling your service
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

When you create your dialog, you can add a cancel listener:

```
pd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO cancel your music service 
            }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work. Even simple Toast. While ProgressDialog is active, pressing back doesn't fire Toast (if to test this). Only cancels dialog

Comment: Try to add a cancel listener to your dialog (just updated my answer)